# Wordpress Different Image per footer

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a WP site and I am trying to achieve the following. I need on 3 different pages a separate image in the footer.
I did find an answer how to do it the following way placing this code in the footer:

```
<?php
if(is_page(4)):
?>
<div class="images"><img src="url-image-location" alt="alt info" class="img-responsive"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The above way works great but i'm lost on how to add it for the another page. I tried just repeating the above code again and changing the page and image url but then I lose styling from the rest of footer.

So question is, how do I add it a second time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `elseif` and just change the image path variable so you won't loose styling? i assume your css is written for class.

```
<?php
$image_path = "imagepath";
if (is_page(4)) {
    $image_path = "imagepath-4";
}
else if (is_page(5)) {
    $image_path = "imagepath-5";
}
else if (is_page(6)) {
    $image_path = "imagepath-6";
}
?>
<div class="images"><img src="<?php echo $image_path?>" alt="alt info" class="img-responsive"></div>
```